# Configure load balancing activemq servers which have only one static load balancing IP

Tags: activemq-classic, load-balancing

This is my scenario. 
I have two consumers server:

- Server A has IP: 192.168.0.1
- Server B has IP: 192.168.0.2

Both servers have configured the activemq as below:

> transportConnector uri="tcp://192.168.0.X:61616"
>   updateClusterClients="true"

In my system, I have one load balancing server (hardware load balancing) which has IP 192.168.0.100 and load balances all requests to above servers.
In the past, my client must configure the connect url as below:

> failover:(tcp://192.168.0.1:61616,tcp://192.168.0.2:61616)

to send active mq message.

In the current, we cannot send message directly to each server and must send to load balancing IP. But when I configure the url as below:

> failover:(tcp://192.168.0.100:61616)

Nothing happens, we can ping to port 61616 but message cannot be sent.
I cannot use the acitvemq load balancing model because client cannot reach the child servers. Can some one help me? Can we configure the activemq to have the virtual client which have the load balanacing ip.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I found that I had researched the wrong way. OpenWire is a two way communication protocol which requried the connected point from both way. So we cannot put them in load balancing which have shared IP. Need to find another way :)